# MongoDB - $lookup not getting an appropriate result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here I just need to look up three tables first need to get all subjects from the subject table according to classid and boardid then from the content table we need to get all topic and content details and group them by topicid(please look into expecting output). then each topic details should contain child details which we will get from edchildrevisioncompleteschemas table
#lookup code

```
const { stageid, subjectid, boardid, scholarshipid, childid } = req.params;
edcontentmaster
.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      stageid: stageid,
      subjectid: subjectid,
      boardid: boardid,
      // scholarshipid: scholarshipid,
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      convertedField: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: ["$slcontent", ""] },
          then: "$slcontent",
          else: { $toInt: "$slcontent" },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      slcontent: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "edchildrevisioncompleteschemas",
      let: { childid: childid, subjectid:subjectid,topicid:"$topicid" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$childid",
                    "$$childid"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$subjectid",
                    "$subjectDetails.subjectid"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$topicid",
                    {
                      $reduce: {
                        input: "$subjectDetails",
                        initialValue: [],
                        in: {
                          $concatArrays: [
                            "$$value",
                            "$$this.topicDetails.topicid"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            childid: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "studenttopic",
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$topic",
      topicimage: { $first: "$topicimage" },
      topicid: { $first: "$topicid" },
      sltopic: { $first: "$sltopic" },
      studenttopic: { $first: "$studenttopic" },
      reviewquestionsets: {
        $push: {
          id: "$_id",
          sub: "$sub",
          topic: "$topic",
          contentset: "$contentset",
          stage: "$stage",
          timeDuration: "$timeDuration",
          contentid: "$contentid",
          studentdata: "$studentdata",
          subjectIamge: "$subjectIamge",
          topicImage: "$topicImage",
          contentImage: "$contentImage",
          isPremium: "$isPremium",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      topic: "$_id",
      topicimage: 1,
      topicid: 1,
      sltopic: 1,
      studenttopic:1,
      contentid: "$contentid",
      reviewquestionsets: 1,
    },
  },
])
.sort({ sltopic: 1 })
.collation({
  locale: "en_US",
  numericOrdering: true,
})
```

from the above query I am getting appropriate data for a single subject, but I need all subjects from subject table and each subject should have the same format data that i getting for a single subject,
ex-mongoplayground.net/p/LoxSBI3jZL-

current output-

```
[
{
"reviewquestionsets": [
  {
    "contentid": "NVOOKADA1690811843420STD-5EnglishThe Monkey 
from RigerLesson - 1",
    "contentset": "Lesson - 1",
    "id": ObjectId("64ccd53792362c7639d3da5f"),
    "stage": "STD-5",
    "timeDuration": "15",
    "topic": "The Monkey from Riger"
  },
  {
    "contentid": "NVOOKADA1690811843420STD-5EnglishThe Monkey 
 from RigerLesson - 3",
    "contentset": "Lesson - 3",
    "id": ObjectId("64ccf5ca92362c7639d3f145"),
    "isPremium": true,
    "stage": "STD-5",
    "timeDuration": "5",
    "topic": "The Monkey from Riger"
  }
],
"sltopic": "1",
"studenttopic": [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("659580293aaddf7594689d18"),
    "childid": "WELL1703316202984"
  }
],
"topic": "The Monkey from Riger",
"topicid": "1691144002706",
"topicimage": ""
}
]
```

expected output-

```
[
{
"_id": "64cc9a2656738e9f1507f521",
"subjectid": "1691130406151",
"subject": "English",
"subjectImage": "https://wkresources.s3.ap-south- 
1.amazonaws.com/1691761437925_644750345.png",
"stageid": "5",
"stage": "STD-5",
"boardid": "1",
"boardname": "BSE",
"scholarshipid": "NVOOKADA1690811843420",
"scholarshipname": "Adarsh",
"createon": "2023-08-04T06:26:46.154Z",
"updatedon": "2023-08-14T13:07:16.256Z",
"__v": 0,
"slsubject": "1",
"topicDetails": {
  "reviewquestionsets": [
    {
      "contentid": "NVOOKADA1690811843420STD-5EnglishThe Monkey 
from RigerLesson - 1",
      "contentset": "Lesson - 1",
      "id": "64ccd53792362c7639d3da5f",
      "stage": "STD-5",
      "timeDuration": "15",
      "topic": "The Monkey from Riger"
    },
    {
      "contentid": "NVOOKADA1690811843420STD-5EnglishThe Monkey 
from RigerLesson - 3",
      "contentset": "Lesson - 3",
      "id": "64ccf5ca92362c7639d3f145",
      "isPremium": true,
      "stage": "STD-5",
      "timeDuration": "5",
      "topic": "The Monkey from Riger"
    }
  ],
  "sltopic": "1",
  "studenttopic": [
    {
      "_id": "659580293aaddf7594689d18",
      "childid": "WELL1703316202984"
    }
  ],
  "topic": "The Monkey from Riger",
  "topicid": "1691144002706",
  "topicimage": ""
}
}
]
```

Comment: Provide some example data to run the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LoxSBI3jZL-

Comment: [Your playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LoxSBI3jZL-) has `$group` before `$lookup` but the code in your question has `$lookup` before `$group`. So which is it? You've said _"not getting an appropriate result"_ but you've not explained what you're getting or why it's incorrect with your example. Your last paragraph is very hard to read. Do you just want **all `edchildrevisioncompleteschemas` for all topics related to a subject**? The subjectId in your example `1691130406151` doesn't exist in `subjects`, only in `edcontentmaster`.

Comment: Updated question, sorry for the confusion. Please check edchildrevisioncompleteschemas collection key is "subjectDetails" "subjectid": "1691130406151" is present there. Getting the expected output for a single subject, but now need to find all subject details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
edSubject.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    stageid: stageid,
    boardid: boardid,
    scholarshipid: scholarshipid,
  },
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "edcontentmasterschemas",
    let: {
      stageid: "$stageid",
      subjectid: "$subjectid",
      boardid: "$boardid",
      scholarshipid: "$scholarshipid",
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ["$stageid", "$$stageid"] },
              { $eq: ["$subjectid", "$$subjectid"] },
              { $eq: ["$boardid", "$$boardid"] },
              { $eq: ["$scholarshipid", "$$scholarshipid"] },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          convertedField: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ["$slcontent", ""] },
              then: "$slcontent",
              else: { $toInt: "$slcontent" },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      { $sort: { slcontent: 1 } },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$topicid",
          topicimage: { $first: "$topicimage" },
          topic: { $first: "$topic" },
          sltopic: { $first: "$sltopic" },
          studenttopic: { $first: "$studenttopic" },
          reviewquestionsets: {
            $push: {
              id: "$_id",
              sub: "$sub",
              topic: "$topic",
              contentset: "$contentset",
              stage: "$stage",
              timeDuration: "$timeDuration",
              contentid: "$contentid",
              studentdata: "$studentdata",
              subjectIamge: "$subjectIamge",
              topicImage: "$topicImage",
              contentImage: "$contentImage",
              isPremium: "$isPremium",
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          convertedField: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ["$slcontent", ""] },
              then: "$slcontent",
              else: { $toInt: "$slcontent" },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      { $sort: { sltopic: 1 } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "edchildrevisioncompleteschemas",
          let: {
            childid: childid,
            //childid,
            //subjectid,
            topicid: "$_id"
          },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$childid",
                        "$$childid"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $in: [
                        "$$topicid",
                        {
                          $reduce: {
                            input: "$subjectDetails",
                            initialValue: [],
                            in: {
                              $concatArrays: [
                                "$$value",
                                "$$this.topicDetails.topicid"
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            {
              $project: {
                _id: 1,
                childid: 1
              }
            }
          ],
          as: "studenttopic"
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          topic: "$_id",
          topicimage: 1,
          topicid: 1,
          sltopic: 1,
          studenttopic: 1,
          contentid: "$contentid",
          reviewquestionsets: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
    as: "topicDetails",
  },
},
{ $unwind: "$topicDetails" }, 
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    subject: { $first: "$subject" },
    subjectid: { $first: "$subjectid" },
    slsubject: { $first: "$slsubject" },
    topicDetails: { $push: "$topicDetails" }, 
  },
},
])
```

Answer (score 4):

You should join the *subject* collection with the *edcontentmaster* via `$lookup`. The `pipeline` in the `$lookup` stage should be your existing query.

In the last stage, convert the `topicDetails` to an object by getting the first element.

```
db.subject.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      stageid: "5",
      boardid: "1",
      scholarshipid: "NVOOKADA1690811843420"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "edcontentmaster",
      let: {
        stageid: "$stageid",
        subjectid: "$subjectid",
        boardid: "$boardid",
        scholarshipid: "$scholarshipid"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$stageid",
                    "$$stageid"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$subjectid",
                    "$$subjectid"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$boardid",
                    "$$boardid"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$scholarshipid",
                    "$$scholarshipid"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            convertedField: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$slcontent",
                    ""
                  ]
                },
                then: "$slcontent",
                else: {
                  $toInt: "$slcontent"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            slcontent: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$topic",
            topicimage: {
              $first: "$topicimage"
            },
            topicid: {
              $first: "$topicid"
            },
            sltopic: {
              $first: "$sltopic"
            },
            studenttopic: {
              $first: "$studenttopic"
            },
            reviewquestionsets: {
              $push: {
                id: "$_id",
                sub: "$sub",
                topic: "$topic",
                contentset: "$contentset",
                stage: "$stage",
                timeDuration: "$timeDuration",
                contentid: "$contentid",
                studentdata: "$studentdata",
                subjectIamge: "$subjectIamge",
                topicImage: "$topicImage",
                contentImage: "$contentImage",
                isPremium: "$isPremium"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "edchildrevisioncompleteschemas",
            let: {
              childid: "WELL1703316202984",
              //childid,
              subjectid: "1691130406151",
              //subjectid,
              topicid: "$topicid"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$childid",
                          "$$childid"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $in: [
                          "$$subjectid",
                          "$subjectDetails.subjectid"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $in: [
                          "$$topicid",
                          {
                            $reduce: {
                              input: "$subjectDetails",
                              initialValue: [],
                              in: {
                                $concatArrays: [
                                  "$$value",
                                  "$$this.topicDetails.topicid"
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  _id: 1,
                  childid: 1
                }
              }
            ],
            as: "studenttopic"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            topic: "$_id",
            topicimage: 1,
            topicid: 1,
            sltopic: 1,
            studenttopic: 1,
            contentid: "$contentid",
            reviewquestionsets: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "topicDetails"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      topicDetails: {
        $first: "$topicDetails"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/byEA90yyNt0)

Comment: Here you also passed single subjectid. but we need to filter all subjects according to their stageid, boardid, and scholarshipid

Comment: For this case, remove the `subjectid` filter criteria in the first `$match` stage.

Comment: yes, but when there is more than one topic with a different topicid but under a single subjectid it's taking only one topic, can please check https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sjhpx5xV13T

Comment: Here topicDetails should be an array and each different topic should be an object.  like subject array

Comment: Your expected output is with `topicDetails` is an object not an array. I think you need to know how to differentiate what is an array (`[]`) and what is an object (`{}`).